# Text won't align under image in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to follow other guides and working on it myself to see what is interfering with the text being unable to align underneth the image.

Any chance anyone has delt with a similar issue?

HTML

```
  <div id="cf">
    <img class="bottom" src="/Images/t-shirtclose.png"  alt="sometext" style="width:400px;height:420px" />
    <img class="top" src="/Images/T-shirt.png"  alt="sometext" style="width:400px;height:420px" />
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

In the CSS the #cf img is interfering with allowing the text to align below it

CSS

```
#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #bbb;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%
}
```

Here is the code
https://jsfiddle.net/Kalilath/ry2aoxc5/1/

Comment: #cf{text-align:center;} #cf p{cler:both;}

Comment: Your images are positioned absolute. Its always tricky to work with absolute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated for the updated question: If you want to centre an item above an absolutely positioned element, you can use the following (and make sure the parent element has `position:relative` as its attribute):

```
#cf p {
    position: absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

If you want to stack your images on top of each other and keep everything in your `#cf` container centred, use `display:flex` on your container.

`flex-direction` set to `column` will stack everything in your container vertically, and `align-items` set to `center` with align everything horizontally in the middle.

```css
#cf {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cf">
    <img class="bottom" src="https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-800x825.jpg"  alt="sometext" style="width:400px;height:420px" />
    <img class="top" src="https://post.medicalnewstoday.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/2020/02/322868_1100-800x825.jpg"  alt="sometext" style="width:400px;height:420px" />
    <p>Some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works great on its own and i understand the css places it below, however if you look at the full code (was too long to put in question) something is interfering with it and i'm not sure what? It just places it inside where the image is and doesnt ever change its align

Comment: I've updated your fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/g1knq0jo/

Comment: I wish i could give you an upvote!! Works like a charm

Comment: You can upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful!

Comment: Sadly i need 15 rep to upvote but i have made it the correct answer